# How to import a static library on an iOS project?

Tags: c++, ios

I'm currently trying to import a very simple C++ static library in an iOS project.

Here is what the static library project looks like (it's a screenshot made with Android Studio, but I actually built it with Xcode 13.2.1):

[image: Static library project]

I managed to generate the library and locate the `.a` file. By running `lipo -info libJuceDemo.a`, I can see that it's a fat file, targeting the `arm64` and the `armv7` architectures.

Now I’m trying to import it on an iOS project, and here is what I did:

- I created a `CPP` group, then a `Juce` group, and copied the `libJuceDemo.a` and `JuceTest.h` files in it, as you can see here:

[image: C++ static library in iOS project]

- If I go to `Runner > Targets > General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`, I can see that `libJuceDemo.a` is here, as expected
- Then I went to `Runner > Project > Build Settings > Search Paths`, and for `Header Search Paths`, I added: `$SRCROOT/Runner/CPP/Juce` (I tried both recursive and non recursive)

Then I tried to call the code of the library from my C++ code of my iOS app:

- I added: `#include "Juce/JuceTest.h"`
- I instantiate the `JuceTest` class as the following: `jucetest::JuceTest juceTest;`

Now when I try to compile and run my iOS app, I get the following error:

```
error: unknown type name 'JuceTest'
```

One more thing: If I go to `Runner > Targets > Build Phases > Dependencies` and click the `+` button, I can't find neither my library nor any of its header file...

Did I miss something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should remove the last path component of `$SRCROOT/Runner/CPP/Juce` in search path, to be `$SRCROOT/Runner/CPP`.

Comment: @prapin Thanks, but no, I see what you mean, but I still get the same error...

Comment: My bad, it was actually an error in another class, it's working now!